# Failed Login with Captcha php even if the test is true

Tags: php, forms, session, post, captcha

I've created a simple form (email, password) with captcha which login to the website. The captcha-code (generated randomly each time the page is refreshed) is saved in `$_SESSION["captcha_code"]` and the captcha written by the user is submitted by the form method post.

To login to the website, we test if the `$_SESSION["captcha_code"]` is equal to `$_POST["captcha_code"]`.

Even if the test is true it can't get access. I don't know what I did wrong.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<section class="login-form">
      <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nom de l'utilisateur/Email...."><br><br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Mot de passe...."><br><br>

        <!-- ======= Captcha Section ======= -->
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:40%;margin:0 auto;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="width:10%;">
                <img src="includes/captcha-gen.inc.php" />
              </td>
              <td colspan="3" style="width:10%;">
                <input type="text" name="captcha_code" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" id="login" name="submit" value="Connecter" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
      </form>

      <?php
      if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
        if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
          echo "<p style='color:red;'>Remplissez tous les champs!</p>";
        } else if ($_GET["error"] == "wronglogin") {
          echo "<p style='color:red;'>Login incorrect!</p>";
        } else if ($_GET["error"] == "incorrectCaptcha") {
          echo "<p style='color:red;'>Captcha incorrect!</p>";
        }
      }
      ?>
</section>
```

login.inc.php

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $_POST["name"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
        // Variable to save the captcha code sent by the form
    $captcha = $_POST["captcha_code"];

        // Data base connexion
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';

        // page where I created the loginUser function
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';

    // Running error handlers and user signup
    if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
                // Here I made a test to compare between the captcha code saved in session and the code sent by the form
        if ($captcha == $_SESSION["captcha_code"]) {
            loginUser($pdo, $username, $pwd);
        }
    } else {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=incorrectCaptcha");
    }
} else {

    header("location: ../login.php");
}
?>
```

the two variables are equal but I can't access with an error message

```
Captcha incorrect!
```

[image]

[image]

```
} else {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=incorrectCaptcha".'/'.$_SESSION["captcha_code"].'-'.$captcha);
    }
```

I've created this test to see the values of each variable which shows that they are equal

Comment: Double-check that they are equal. Try `var_dump($captcha); var_dump($_SESSION["captcha_code"]);` to see what you get

Comment: Actually, you never get to the captcha check, because you exit right before that line. Your incorrectCaptcha is if $username or $pwd are empty, and those inputs do not exist in. your form

Comment: Learn to, while debugging an issue, to output `var_dump` or `print_r` the outputs you are checking/comparing, this will take you a long way. You can later cleanup/remove these checks..

Comment: Sorry guys, I ve checked the outputs with print-r and they are equal but the same problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ponder on the logic below for a short while:

```
    // Running error handlers and user signup
    if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
                // Here I made a test to compare between the captcha code saved in session and the code sent by the form
        if ($captcha == $_SESSION["captcha_code"]) {
            loginUser($pdo, $username, $pwd);
        }
    } else {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=incorrectCaptcha");
    }
```

The outer `if` checks whether `emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false`. If that's false, then your captcha check will not even run and it will jump straight to your `else`, which redirects somewhere else.

It's clear that `$username` will have the value of the `form` element whose `name` is `name` and `$pwd` will have the value of the `form` element whose `name` is `pwd`.

Since you have not shared the code of `emptyInputLogin` nor `loginUser`, I'm not sure what should exactly happen, but it seems that `emptyInputLogin` returns `false`, because you have set both `name` and `pwd`. If so, then the fix will be

```
    // Running error handlers and user signup
    if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) !== false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
    } else {
        // Here I made a test to compare between the captcha code saved in session and the code sent by the form
        if ($captcha == $_SESSION["captcha_code"]) {
            loginUser($pdo, $username, $pwd);
        } else {
            header("location: ../login.php?error=incorrectCaptcha");
        }
    }
```

which moves the captcha check to the else of the main `if` so captcha check will only happen if username and password were properly set. If the captcha check succeeded, then `loginUser` will be called and, if the captcha check failed, that is, the captcha did not match the expected value, then a redirect will be occurring towards the incorrectCaptcha page (login.php with error being incorrectCaptcha)